# export 'a-component' (imported as 'i1') was not found in 'module' (possible exports: x-component, module)

Tags: javascript, angular

When I create angular library -> i build and pack lib -> then i add new component in library -> i rebuild and pack lib. but when i call component, i got the error as shown:
export 'a-component' (imported as 'i1') was not found in 'module' (possible exports: x-component, module)
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LevnR.png)

I got the error in the both window and macOS environments

I used angular 15
What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Did you add the new component to the library's NgModule's declarations+exports, and to the public-api.ts?

Comment: In fact, if you're still stuck, please add to your question the contents of your library's main module (`<library-name>.module.ts`), the `public-api.ts`, and maybe your `angular.json`. Where are you trying to consume your library - from an application project within the same Angular workspace or from somewhere else?